# Could not build url for endpoint 'otp' with values ['adhar_no']. Did you mean 'vote' instead?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask

can anyone help  me with this code from flask I am getting this error
Could not build url for endpoint 'otp' with values ['adhar_no']. Did you mean 'vote' instead?

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for,redirect





parties=["A","B","C","D"]


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('home.html')
    #return render_template('admin.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    adhar_no = request.form['aadhar_num']

    return redirect(url_for('otp',adhar_no=adhar_no))
    return render_template('otp.html',adhar_no=adhar_no)

@app.route('/otp',methods = ['POST'])
def verification():
    a_no=request.args.get('adhar_no')
    otp_text = request.form['otp']
    return a_no

HTML CODE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VERIFY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Verification</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for("verification")}}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="otp" required pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength=4 id="userCode" ng-model="formdata.userCode" title="4 Digit code">&nbsp;
                <label>Enter otp </label>
            </div>
            <strong>{{error}}</strong> 
            <button class="btn">VERIFY</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/static/js/sjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and I am getting this error

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'otp' with values ['adhar_no']. Did you mean 'vote' instead?

Answer (score 0):

Flask `url_for` will require a function name. You were passing the `otp`  and there is no `otp` function hence the error

```
return redirect(url_for('.verification',adhar_no=adhar_no))
```

For `verification` function in `/otp` route you  will also need to change the function signature.

Refer to the [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.url_for) documentation for more info

Answer (score 0):

Note: `url_for` function take input of your existing route function.

`return redirect(url_for('otp',adhar_no=adhar_no))`

here you passed `otp` in `url_for` as a function name(which does not exist in your existing routes),

whereas you must pass `verification` in `url_for`.

E.g: `return redirect(url_for('verification',adhar_no=adhar_no))`

Anyhow, Your verification function accepting only POST request, and you are trying to send query param `adhar_no` with GET request.

Comment: like in above code after modificatiton of return redirect(url_for('otp',adhar_no=adhar_no)) to return redirect(url_for('verification',adhar_no=adhar_no)) the flask app is only redirecting to verification but not rendering otp.html page canu please help me with this